# Can you create struct tags in a separate file?

Tags: go

*This is not a duplicate of [How can I override json tags in a Go struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909177/how-can-i-override-json-tags-in-a-go-struct) - that asks an entirely different question!*

Given this XML struct:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar         string `xml:"bar"`
}
```

I'd like to define *`xml:"bar"`* in a config' file, elsewhere. Something like:

```
import (
    "github.com/foo/app/config"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar         string config.Bar
}
```

Where *github.com/foo/app/config* contains the following:

```
package config

const (
    Bar = `xml:"bar"`
)
```

That doesn't work, though - any help to achieve something similar would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplication? I don't think so - the suggested duplicate question doesn't even come close. Besides, it seems it's impossible (see below). That is much more useful feedback...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you create struct tags in a separate config file?

No.

You even cannot change them during runtime.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: See [Struct Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) in the reference. As you can see, only string *literals* are allowed for tags. So no variables or other expressions that are more complicated than raw strings.

Comment: @Kisinga The language spec is the documentation for everything about the language. The fancy stuff you can do during runtime is through package reflect where you find no function or method to change struct tags.

Comment: That's a shame - I have numerous structs, some of whose fields share the VERY SAME TAG. Would be good to share the string across those fields. Ah well :(